# Eloquent dando erro 500 com muitos resultados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou realizando uma consulta em minha base com alguns LEFT JOIN e algumas clausulas WHERE, porém, estou tendo uma série de dificuldades com relação ao retorno dessa query que, por ter muitos resultados, simplesmente após um certo tempo de processamento dá erro 500. Por exemplo:

- Fiz a query e a executei retornando apenas 1 resultado - funcionou;
- Fiz a query retornando um curto espaço de tempo (5 dias apenas) com aproximadamente 9 mil registros - Funcionou;
- Fiz a consulta com 15 dias, retornaria aproximadamente 30 mil registros - Não funciona, dá erro 500.
- Fiz a consulta com 14 dias, retornou aproximadamente 28 mil registros - Funcionou O.o

Neste caso, existe a necessidade, por parte do cliente de retornar dados de até 60 dias e da forma que está, não funciona.

Segue a query:

```
$this->clientes->select('clientes.id', 'clientes.nome', 'clientes.email', 'clientes.created_at',
            'clientes.updated_at AS ultima_atualizacao', 'origem.titulo AS titulo_origem',
            'clientes.sexo', 'produtos.nome AS nome_produto', 'clientes.tipo_logradouro',
            'clientes.telefone1', 'clientes.telefone2', 'clientes.telefone3',
            'clientes.logradouro', 'clientes.numero', 'clientes.complemento', 'clientes.bairro',
            'clientes.cidade', 'clientes.estado', 'clientes.cep', 'clientes.status',
            'usuarios.susep_principal', 
            'produto_auto_veiculo.marca', 'produto_auto_veiculo.modelo', 'produto_auto_veiculo.ano_fabricacao',
            'produto_auto_veiculo.ano_modelo', 'atendimento_cliente.hora_vinculo',
            'atendimento_cliente.created_at AS ultimo_contato')
        ->leftJoin('atendimento_cliente', 'clientes.id', '=', 'atendimento_cliente.id_cliente')
        ->leftJoin('produtos', 'produtos.id', '=', 'atendimento_cliente.id_produto')
        ->leftJoin('origem', 'origem.id', '=', 'clientes.id_origem')
        ->leftJoin('usuarios', 'usuarios.id', '=', 'clientes.id_corretor')
        ->leftJoin('pedidos', 'usuarios.id', '=', 'pedidos.id_cliente')
        ->leftJoin('produto_auto_veiculo', 'produto_auto_veiculo.pedido_id', '=', 'pedidos.id')
        ->orderBy('clientes.' . $inputs['ordem'], 'desc')
        ->groupBy('clientes.id')
        ->get()
```

Comment: Where is the `Where` ?

Comment: There is a method that implements the `WHERE` if is requested. Look an example: `->where('estado', $this->inputs['name_search']);`, but it isn't obligatory on query, just is called if a request is filtered. In this example, I have the same problem, if I return one data with `first()` of eloquent, it works, but if I return with `get()` give 500 error.

Comment: Eu falo português, eu só fiz uma brincadeira usando o `where`. Não tem nada errado quando você escolhe 15 dias para fazer a consulta ? Seu arquivo `config.php` na pasta `app` está com `debug => true` ?

Comment: Qual é o erro especifico? erro 500 é generico não diz qual é a raiz do problema.

Comment: Provavelmente exaustão da memória. Para essas coisas não ocorrerem, eu sempre uso paginação. Se for o caso, implemente infinite scroll na sua aplicação.

Comment: Dois problemas, o primeiro é que simplesmente não apresenta o erro em si, só erro 500. Debug habilitado, renderização de tela de erro nativa Ok, feito testes em outras páginas simulando erro 500 funcionando, mas só nesse caso não retorna nada. Verifiquei o log do Laravel e também não tive retorno algum do erro. Referente a paginação, não posso usar, esses dados são necessários para gerar um CSV. ;(

Comment: Você deve separar a parte da resposta da questão, depois de alguns minutos aceite a resposta(sinal verde), significa que o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **RESOLVIDO**
>
> Pessoal, consegui resolver o problema, entre aspas, mas atende as necessidades da empresa. Eu já tinha uma interface pra implementar diversos relatórios através de script, ou seja, bastava criar um `Command` no Laravel e informar qual o script e ele executaria por trás. Criei um arquivo `.sh` para essa rotina.
>
> Quanto ao problema, o mesmo não ocorria especificamente no `Eloquent`, mas sim no próprio PHP que não suportava a quantidade de dados, consegui a partir da minha máquina pessoal debugar o código e identifiquei que quando o resultado era colocado dentro de um array, até uma certa quantidade funcionava, porém, em dado momento, estourava a memória do servidor.